# Rebasing master without being able to push --force

Tags: git, git-push

I have my branch, say `foo`, that is also on origin. I'm the only one coding to this branch. Meanwhile, master changed and I need to pull those changes and then make some more changes onto my branch and push it. So I go ahead and:

```
git checkout foo
get rebase master
git commit ...
git push origin foo
```

Except this fails because it's not a fast-forward. I would normally do `--force` but we don't allow it here. If I pull `origin/foo` then I either get a bunch of conflicts that had to do with the `master` changes or my new changes in `foo`.

What is the correct workflow for a solo branch without `--force`?

Comment: I would delete `foo` on `origin` and push it again, or make a `foo-new`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `merge master` to your `foo` instead of `rebase` it on `master`.

1. git checkout foo
2. git pull origin foo
3. git merge master

Solve conflicts, commit some changes and so on...
And then you can `push` back to `origin` without `--force`

4. git push origin foo

After your finish with your branch and if you want to merge to stable branch you have to merge your `foo` branch to `master`:

5. git checkout master
6. git merge foo
7. git push origin master

---

```
foo: 0-----0--------(step2)---(step3)------0----0
                              /                   \
master: 0-------0------------0---------------------(step6)
```